# MYSQL - Counting with unique value

Tags: mysql

I have this table for example

```
IP ADDRESS  | DATE

10.10.10.10 | 2014-09-01    
10.10.10.10 | 2014-09-12    
44.33.33.33 | 2014-09-12    
10.10.10.10 | 2014-09-15    
44.33.33.33 | 2014-09-16    
33.10.31.33 | 2014-09-18    
89.99.11.22 | 2014-09-18
44.33.33.33 | 2014-09-19 
33.10.31.33 | 2014-09-22
10.10.10.10 | 2014-09-24
```

and what i want from the table is

```
TOTAL UNIQUE IP | DATE

1         | 2014-09-01 <-- 10.10.10.10
1         | 2014-09-12 <-- 44.33.33.33
2         | 2014-09-18 <-- 33.10.31.33 and 89.99.11.22
```

please help me :)

rules :

- ignore after the first time ipaddress accessed
- sorry for my bad english

Comment: what you have tried so far, show it

Comment: @DanFromGermany I think its supposed to reflect "distinct IPs per date"

Comment: @DanFromGermany: It seems that it's number of unique ips per day

Comment: i meant that's not 1, but counting how many unique ip accessed. actually this table is result from joining two tables. and i have no idea how to make like i want

Comment: From what I understood he wants to display for each date the number of IPs that appeared for the 1st time. For example on 2014-09-15 10.10.10.10 should not be counted because it already appeared on  2014-09-01.

Comment: Why not `1 | 2014-09-15` ? You need to be much more specific about the rules you want to implement. Otherwise all you will get is wild guesses.

Comment: @StephaneM exactly :)

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate grouped by date, count only distinct ip addresses:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ip_address),
    t1.date
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT ip_address
    FROM table
    WHERE t1.ip_address = t2.ip_address AND t1.date < t2.date
    LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY t1.date
ORDER BY t1.date
```

If you want to see the addresses:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address),
    date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip_address)
FROM table
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: nope, it will show all unique ip by date. what i want is, counting the first time that ip address access :)

Comment: unfortunately, it returns with wrong result. here is the real table http://prntscr.com/4rpf9p

and by using your code, the result is this, http://prntscr.com/4rpfkf

actually it should be

1 | 2014-07-01
1 | 2014-08-01
2 | 2014-09-29

anyway, thank you for your helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Refining answer from @DanFromgermany

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address),
    date
FROM table t1
where ip_address not in (select ip_address from table t2 where t2.date < t1.date)
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: I think this is closer to what the OP wants. Maybe instead of IN, `WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ip_address FROM table... LIMIT 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ip_address, MIN(`date`), COUNT(DISTINCT `date`) 
FROM `table`
GROUP BY ip_address;
```

(BTW it's almost always a bad idea to store ip addresses as dotted quad strings)

If the number of ip addresses is small relative to the number of records (less than 2%, depending on table and index structure) then a NOT EXISTS sub clause will be more efficient than the full table scan described here.